# flattening only part of a matrix, manipulating and retrieving the unflattened matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, vector

I start with a square matrix with odd size. I keep the original version of this matrix. Now, I extract the non-zero elements from the matrix, which lie everywhere except the $3\times3$ block in the center of the matrix, flatten them out and do some manipulations. These manipulations required me to remove the zero elements. Now I want to unflatten these elements into their original positions in the matrix and retrieve the matrix as a whole. I tried assigning labels to each of the elements but that becomes cumbersome. (I am working with a multidimensional array; the matrix here is just for example). How can I do this easily?

Comment: Use `SparseArray` and `ArrayRules`.

Comment: `matrix={{a,b,c,d},{e,f,g,h},{i,j,k,l},{m,n,o,p}};(*for example*)
For[y=2,y<=3,y++,For[z=2,z<=3,z++, matrix[[y,z]]=""]];(*or another placeholder*)
manipulated=doSomeManipulations[Flatten[matrix]];
Partition[manipulated,4]//MatrixForm`

Answer (score 1):

`a = SparseArray[RandomChoice[Range[10], {10, 5}]];
a[[Range[2, 4], Range[2, 4]]] = 0;
SparseArray[a["NonzeroPositions"] -> manipulations[a["NonzeroValues"]]]`

Where manipulations is the function you want to perform on the flattened values

Comment: I need to flatten the non-zero entries to do the manipulations (not needed but this is because I am finding the nullspace of the a bunch of vectors stored on those positions of nonzero entries in the matrix.)

Comment: In the above code `a["NonzeroValues"]` gives flattened non zero entries of the matrix `a`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that is similar to @no-one's, but packaged differently:

```
nonzeroMap[func_, array_] := Replace[SparseArray[array],
    Verbatim[SparseArray][a__, {b__, c_}] :> Normal @ SparseArray[a,{b,func/@c}]
]
```

A `SparseArray` object stores the nonzero elements in the last position of the last argument. So, the above function converts the input array into a SparseArray, maps `func` onto the nonzero elements, and then converts back to a normal array. Here are a couple examples:

*random matrix*

```
m = RandomInteger[3, {4,4}];
m //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  3 & 3 & 2 & 0 \\
>  2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
>  1 & 3 & 2 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
nonzeroMap[1/#&, m] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
>  \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
>  1 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

*random array*

```
a = RandomInteger[3, {3,3,3}];
a //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \{2,1,2\} & \{3,3,2\} & \{2,0,2\} \\
>  \{1,1,1\} & \{0,3,1\} & \{2,2,0\} \\
>  \{2,3,1\} & \{3,0,3\} & \{0,1,0\} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
nonzeroMap[1/#&, a] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \left\{\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{2}\right\} & \left\{\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}\right\} &
>    \left\{\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2}\right\} \\
>  \{1,1,1\} & \left\{0,\frac{1}{3},1\right\} & \left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0\right\} \\
>  \left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},1\right\} & \left\{\frac{1}{3},0,\frac{1}{3}\right\} & \{0,1,0\} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$